# -performDragOperation: not called when dragging from dock stack

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsview

Hi I have a custom view inside of a status item. I implemented a drag and drop and it all works but when dragging from a dock stack, all of the dragging methods are called except for `-performDragOperation:` and `prepareForDragOperation:`

Comment: Same issue here, at least on Snow Leopard. Pretty odd.

Comment: See related question and workaround here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534543/weird-behavior-dragging-from-stacks-to-status-item-doesnt-work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Does draggingEnded: get called?
If so, just call it from there.

I know the issue from NSStatusItem. There's the same problem

Comment: Important: Remember to use the code from [this related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9534543/weird-behavior-dragging-from-stacks-to-status-item-doesnt-work) to check for cursor position when doing this workaround, else the drop will be performed even if the user drags the item away from the status item.